# Apache Spring - Bean with multiple line property value

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to break up a Spring bean's property value so it is on multiple lines?

```
<bean>
    <property name="something" value="Hello, this is a red fox jumping over a not very brown cow.">
</bean>
```

I know in Java property files, I can put a "\" at the end of each line, but the following does not work with a Spring bean's property value:

```
<bean>
    <property name="something" value="Hello, this is a \
                                      red fox jumping over a \
                                      not very brown cow.">
</bean>
```

Comment: try `&#10;` instead of `\newline`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML attributes are allowed to span lines, and non-space white-space characters are replaced by spaces by the parser.  So for your example you could use:

```
<bean name="foo" class="Foo">
    <property name="bah" value=
"Hello, this is a
red fox jumping over a
not very brown cow." />
</bean>
```

Then the value of 'bah' in 'foo' will be

```
"Hello, this is a red fox jumping over a not very brown cow."
```

If you try and make it tidy like this however

```
<bean name="foo" class="Foo">
    <property name="bah" value=
        "Hello, this is a
        red fox jumping over a
        not very brown cow." />
</bean>
```

You will get extra space characters in the parsed result.

```
Hello, this is a    red fox jumping over a    not very brown cow.
```

Comment: Ahh, I should have been thinking of it as XML! Thanks!